# PHP monitoring with Nagios

Tags: php, monitoring, nagios

I want to monitor and profile PHP based system. For profiling I will use xdebug. My question is whether I can use Nagios for monitoring ? Also, if the answer is yes, does anyone have experience with this configuration ?

Comment: You just want to know if anyone has experience with Nagios? Because the answer would simply be 'yes'. If you need some specific questions answered you should ask them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is whether I can use Nagios for monitoring ?

Yes, Nagios is a software to monitor computer systems and network services they offer.

> Also, if the answer is yes, does anyone have experience with this configuration?

Yes there are persons who have experience with configuring Nagios or it's forks. You can get professional technical support from these vendors.

Additional many resources are availble for free in the world wide web.

Comment: my main question is about the combination of Nagios with PHP. Does it common ? Does it acceptable ?

Comment: What do you mean? Write Nagios frontends in PHP? Execute PHP by Nagios to test if it is running? You need to be more specific to actually formulate a question at all. Normally you test daemons with nagios, not if a specific application can execute, like PHP. However you can test if the PHP FCGI daemon is still running for example, or the webserver.

Comment: let me explain. I have a server that running e-learning software based on moodle. The application is writing in PHP. I want to know whether I can monitor it with Nagios. By monitoring I mean, see whether it is alive. whether request average time remain stable, whether they are MySQL problems etc. etc.

Comment: That is exactly what Nagios is for, yes ([Nagios is the industry standard in IT infrastructure monitoring](http://www.nagios.org/) for a reason).